# Hide vertical scrollbar in 2 tables, but allow full scroll in one table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to scroll the whole table together, but having just one vertical scrollbar at the right.
(The scroll can be done by using the vertical scrollbar at the right, through mousewheel or arrows)

I was able to do that, except that I can't hide the vertical scrollbar from the `.fixedTable-body` and when I use the mousewheel or arrows hover the `.fixedTable-sidebar` and `.fixedTable-body` tables, the vertical scrollbar at the right just acts weird.

**What I was able to do:**

- Implement and connect the scroll in all tables body (*Js in working fiddle below*);
- Hide vertical scrollbar in `.fixedTable-sidebar` for Webkit browsers and IE (*haven't found solution to hide for FF*) --> this was done by:

```js
.fixedTable-sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; /* hide scrollbar for Webkit Browsers */
}
.fixedTable-sidebar {
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* hide scrollbar for IE */
}
```

**What I have tried:**

- the pseudo class `:vertical` for webkit browsers, but doesn't work;

```js
.fixedTable-body::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    display: none;
}
```

- Not sure if this `-ms-overflow-y-style` exists for IE, but I tried and doesn't work either;

```js
.fixedTable-body {
    -ms-overflow-y-style: none;
}
```

- Also tried to hide the vertical scrollbar with padding, but wasn't able to do it.

[image: Explanatory Image]

---

**EDIT**

I was able to hide the vertical scrollbars from `.fixedTable-sidebar` and `.fixedTable-body` by creating an outer `div` in both elements and giving it `overflow: hidden`, then make the inner elements `.fixedTable-sidebar` and `.fixedTable-body` slightly bigger `width > 100%` --> with this I was able to hide the scrollbars for all browsers.

Now the **only problem** is the behaviour of the right vertical scrollbar when scroll over the `.fixedTable-sidebar` and `.fixedTable-body` (by using the mouse wheel or the keypad arrows)

[See Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju_Oliveira/60s4pLz5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a **solution** to hide the vertical bar at the middle of the table, but the vertical bar from the right still acts weird, but here it goes in case someone needs it :)

---

I was able to hide the vertical scrollbars from `.fixedTable-sidebar` and `.fixedTable-body` by creating an outer div in both elements and giving it `overflow: hidden`, then make the inner elements `.fixedTable-sidebar` and `.fixedTable-body` slightly bigger `width > 100%` --> with this I was able to hide the scrollbars for all browsers --> **so it's a cross-browser solution**

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju_Oliveira/60s4pLz5/) --> Only 1 vertical and 1 horizontal scrollbar table (with multiple tables inside and fixed header)

P.S.: I will open another question regarding the weird behaviour of the vertical scrollbar, then I'll post a link here :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want to hide the scroll bar, but you want to be still able to scroll. Normally, it will work for what I'm calling modern browsers (Safari, Chrome and Opera) :

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Already did that for the left part of the table, as I stated above (modern browsers --> webkit browsers), now I want to apply it to the middle of the table, but only remove the vertical scrollbar and keep the horizontal

Comment: Even if I change your code to `overflow-y: hidden` it will remove the vertical scroll ability, but thanks anyway! :)